# Enable/disable heavily nested input in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a div with an id; inside that there’s another div with a class, that has another div with another class, that has another div with another class, that has a label, that has an input tag. So it’s

```
div (id) → div (class) → div (class) → div (class) → label → input
```

What I want to do is click that input box. I’ll be using applescript to do it, but that should not be an impediment (I’ll just tell chrome to execute some specific javascript on the page), although it means no jQuery or other libraries. The id will change, but that should be easy to account for, while the classes, whilst all different from one another, will always be the same.

I don’t have much experience with javascript, but I should be able to understand the code, assuming it can be done with a single line/command (which I think it can).

Comment: Is there any id fix or unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this parent div only has one input child, that's pretty easy

HTML :

```
<div id="test">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" onclick="alert('yo');"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do something on Chrome’s settings page, but it appears you cannot run javascript there.

Comment: You can use the developer console to execute javascript. Use F12 shortcut to display it (same key in most browsers)

Comment: That still does not work to select the box inside Chrome’s settings.